# Active Directory OAuth 2.0 - Request an Authorization Code through PHP different than browser request

Tags: php, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code

Under, **REQUEST AN AUTHORIZATION CODE**, it gives a sample code involving an endpoint for `OAuth 2.0`. I've followed this structure to base my own request resembling:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://example.com
&response_mode=query
&resource=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&state=12345
```

During my tests, I've even tried (getting the request as bare as possible):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
```

*Here's the interesting thing*: If I access these domains through the browser, they return a "successful" call, like so:

```
https://example.com/?code=AOA...................................
```

However, I can't seem to get this same result (acquire a code) through a `PHP` workaround.

I've tried:

```
file_get_contents($my_url);
```

But all that returns is an error and a login page for Microsoft.

I've also tried doing so in `cURL`, but no luck.

Can anyone advise on how to replicate getting such a code (automatically)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need here was to access APIs as a user later as well.

When you redeem an authorization code, you get an access token and a refresh token. The access token you attach to API calls, and expires in 1 hour by default. But the refresh token expires in 14 days by default, and *can be used to get a new access token and refresh token*. So you can have perpetual access as long as you use the refresh token to get new tokens always within 14 days.

The user's access will be checked every time you refresh, so if their account is disabled or access is removed, you will get an error instead of new tokens.

---

Short answer: you can't. To get an authorization code, you must redirect the browser so the user can sign in, go through MFA if necessary, sign in to their org local AD... As an end result, the user will be sent back to your app with the code, which you can then redeem for access tokens to APIs you want to call that are protected by Azure AD.

Comment: Is there anyway to pass in user/pass credentials to login automatically and then be redirected to the page with the code?

Comment: You can pass in the username as a parameter when redirecting, but not the password.

Comment: Actually, better question - When requesting an `access_token` a `refresh_token` comes with it. Couldn't someone just keep using the `refresh_token` to continuously get access?

Comment: Absolutely, when you use a refresh token, you get back a new refresh toke and access token.

Comment: Great! Going about it this way, does the access token have an expiration date if not used for a long time? I read somewhere it might only have a lifespan of 90 days if not used.

Comment: Access tokens are valid for one hour by default. So you have to refresh them once in a while. Refresh tokens do not expire unless they are revoked. Though you should still replace the refresh token with the new one you get. Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes

Comment: And right, technically refresh tokens expire in 14 days by default (max 90 days through custom policy). But you can get new refresh tokens as long as do it always within the 2 week period.

Comment: One more question - if say on the 13th day, I get a new refresh token, but don't use the access token to authenticate to the application, will that new refresh token expire only after a day?

Comment: No, the new refresh token will again expire in 14 days.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect user to microsoft login page by using header() function to send HTTP Location header:

```
header("Location: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxxxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost:8088/testauth.php%2F&response_mode=query&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2F&state=12345");
```

After user entered username/password , azure ad will redirect to redirect url with code , you could get the code by :

```
echo $_GET['code'];
```